# MySQL database : how to write SQL for several tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to create a view for  client shipment documents  which contains next info:
    good name,
    good count 
    good price.

Price may be different from one purchase agreement to other. For each purchase agreement may exists several shipments. Each good item in client_shipment_details may has serial number, but client_shipment document
keeps just total count of such kind of good.
This is my tables:

```
purchase_agreement;
+------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------- --------+
 | Field                        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
 +------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
 | id                           | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
 | purchase_agreement_status_id | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                   |
+------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

purchase_agreement_details;
+-----------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                 | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra           |
+-----------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                    | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| count                 | int(11)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                  |
| price                 | float      | NO   |     | NULL    |                 |
| purchase_agreement_id | bigint(20) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                 |
| good_id               | bigint(20) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
 +-----------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

 goods;
 +-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
 | Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
 +-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
 | id          | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
 | name        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
 +-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+


 client_shipment;
 -----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+---------------+
 | Field                 | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra           |
 +-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
 | id                    | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
 | jhi_date              | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                  |
 | purchase_agreement_id | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                 |
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+


client_shipment_details;
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                 | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
|
| serial_number      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| client_shipment_id | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| good_id            | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

This is my query :

```
SELECT
    temp1.cs_id, temp1.good_id, temp1.count, temp1.price,good.name
FROM
   (
      SELECT csd.cs_id AS cs_id, csd.good_id AS good_id, csd.count AS count, pad.price AS price
      FROM
          (
            SELECT client_shipment_id AS cs_id, good_id, count(*) AS count
            FROM client_shipment_details
            GROUP BY client_shipment_id, good_id
          ) AS csd
      LEFT JOIN
          (
            SELECT pad.good_id AS good_id, pad.price AS price, cs.id AS cs_id
            FROM purchase_agreement_details pad
            JOIN client_shipment cs ON pad.purchase_agreement_id = cs.purchase_agreement_id
          ) AS pad ON csd.good_id = pad.good_id
      GROUP BY cs_id,good_id
  ) AS temp1
JOIN goods ON temp1.good_id = good.id
ORDER BY cs_id,good_id;
```

Some test data:

```
insert into purchase_agreement values 
(1,1),
(2,1);

insert into purchase_agreement_details values 
(1,2,100,1,1),
(2,4,200,1,2),
(3,6,300,1,3),
(4,7,400,1,4),
(5,3,110,2,1),
(6,8,210,2,2),
(7,4,310,2,3),
(8,5,410,2,4);


insert into goods values 
(1,"desk"),
(2,"sofa"),
(3,"chair"),
(4,"bed");


insert into client_shipment values 
(1,'2019-02-21 09:57:00',1),
(2,'2019-02-21 09:57:00',1),
(3,'2019-02-21 09:57:00',2),
(4,'2019-02-21 09:57:00',2);

insert into client_shipment_details values 
(1,"1-0001",1,1),
(2,"1-0002",1,1),
(3,"2-0001",1,2),
(4,"2-0002",1,2),
(5,"3-0001",1,3),
(6,"3-0002",1,3),
(7,"4-0001",1,4),
(8,"4-0002",1,4),
(9,"1-0003",2,1),
(10,"1-0004",2,1),
(11,"2-0003",2,2),
(12,"2-0004",2,2),
(13,"3-0003",2,3),
(14,"3-0004",2,3),
(15,"4-0003",2,4),
(16,"4-0004",2,4),
(17,"1-0005",3,1),
(18,"1-0006",3,1),
(19,"2-0005",3,2),
(20,"2-0006",3,2),
(21,"3-0005",3,3),
(22,"3-0006",3,3),
(23,"4-0005",3,4),
(24,"4-0006",3,4),
(25,"1-0007",4,1),
(26,"1-0008",4,1),
(27,"2-0007",4,2),
(28,"2-0008",4,2),
(29,"3-0007",4,3),
(30,"3-0008",4,3),
(31,"4-0007",4,4),
(32,"4-0008",4,4);
```

I'd like to get such result :

```
client_shipment_id  good_name   price count

1                   desk        100     2
1                   sofa        200     2                 
1                   chair       300     2
1                   bed         400     2
2                   desk        100     2
2                   sofa        200     2                 
2                   chair       300     2
2                   bed         400     2
3                   desk        110     2
3                   sofa        210     2                 
3                   chair       310     2
3                   bed         410     2
4                   desk        110     2
4                   sofa        210     2                 
4                   chair       310     2
4                   bed         410     2
```

Comment: i advice you to read [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) and provide example data and expected results.

Comment: "I need to create a view for client shipment documents which contains next info: good name, good count good price." If your query is correct you can simply do   `CREATE VIEW view_name AS your_query`.. Please keep in mind that views with a GROUP BY will optimize and most likely will run badly because them can't be optimized with `ALGORTIHM=MERGE`

Comment: Your `GROUP BY` does not seam to be valid not ANSI SQL or MySQL [functional dependency](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html) valid can you can get invalid data for the non aggregated  columns in the select which are not in the GROUP BY, the GROUP BY columns are not selected on primary or unique keys.

Comment: Check my answer and add comments depending on Your needs

Comment: I updated my question. The field "price in "purchase_agreement_details" was shifted and  wasn't visible . I  have corrected.

Comment: @harp1814 can You fix Your second insert query to be correct with order of fields in purchase_agreement_details  table?

Comment: Sorry for mistake. i fixed.